# String and Integer input Python

Tags: python, string, input, integer, exit

I need it so that I can input both integer and string values. This is because i need a 'quit' function, which enables to quit the program.

```
   movex = int(input("\nDesired X position, or quit >> "))
    if movey == "q" or movex == "q":
        break
    if movex < gsize and movex >= 0:
        #Do stuff
    movey = int(input("Desired Y position, or quit >> "))
    if movey < gsize and movey >= 0:
        #Do stuff
```

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Looks like Python, maybe?

Comment: Yes, python 3.4.3. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using python, what i suppose by your sintax you could do the following:

```
import sys # if you want this what i said in later text...`
movex = raw_input("\nDesired X position, or quit >> ")
if movex == "q":
    break 
# don't really know what you want to do with this but i think you want to use sys.exit() to quit your porgram

movey = raw_input("\nDesired Y position, or quit >> ")
if movey == "q":
    break #same as in first...
try:
    movex_int = int(movex)
    movey_int = int(movey)
    if movex_int < gsize and movex_int >= 0:
          #Do stuff
    if movey_int < gsize and movey_int >= 0:
          #Do stuff

except ValueError: #if not an int the user didn't enter "q" but not either a number
    sys.exit() #this will exit program because parameters aren't expected, but you can do what you want
```

For python3 just use input instead of raw_input :)

Comment: Sorry, yeah Python 3, however, python 3 does not have raw_input

Comment: Then just use input :)

Comment: Hi, but surely this is dependent on the fact that the user enters "q" at the first input

Comment: if he enters on first, it will exit on first :) and if he enters on second it will exit on second... i don't know how this fits into your code , i mean what it's surrounded with

Comment: What if he enters an integer at first?

Comment: well it continues to second input logicly because he didn't enter 'q' then if he doesn't enter 'q' on second it uses that variables and tries to parse integers from them, if the are not integers it will exit program , if they are they are contained in movex_int, and movey_int :)